# ulong, long conversion woes

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have the following code in C# :

```
ulong value1 = 0x11234;
long value2 = (long) value1;

Console.WriteLine(value1);
Console.WriteLine(value2);
```

which produces :

```
70196
70196
```

Shouldn't this have been different since 70196 would be a negative number when converting to long?

[Does the cast automatically change the bitwise value?]

Comment: Why do you expect it to be a negative number? (not my downvote)

Comment: @Hele there are tons of examples on line for converting ulong to long do a google search

Comment: @sayse since the bits mean different things for ulong and long

Comment: @Hele: No, they don't.  2^63 is far larger than that.

Comment: @MethodMan I found many resources to do the conversion, my question is why this particular piece of code behaves as such.

Comment: oh the highest one does - but that's way above 70196 for long :D

Comment: Only a single bit has a different meaning between long and ulong in a twos complement representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Negative numbers are indicated by the sign bit, which is the highest bit; in a `long`, that’s `0x8000000000000000`, and that’s bigger than 70196 when interpreted as a `ulong`.

```
$ cat > test.cs
using System;

static class Application {
    static void Main() {
        ulong a = 0x8000000000000000;
        long b = (long)a;

        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}
$ mcs test.cs
$ mono test.exe
9223372036854775808
-9223372036854775808
```

Answer (score 6):

The bit representation of a 64-bit integer `0x11234` is `0x0000000000011234`. It is extended with 0s in front, not 1s.

When converted from ulong to long, this is still `0x0000000000011234`. A negative number would be `0x8000000000011234` (the MSB is set to 1).